# Use Google Chrome Puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, headless

I'm on Debian 8.7.1.

I want to use Google Chrome Puppeteer.

I have a file named script.js, and I put the getting screenshot commands as recommended in the Puppeteer documentation.

For running the JavaScript file, I run the following command:

```
nodejs script.js
```

But it has some errors:

```
(node:929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection   (rejection id: 2): AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Chromium  revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install"

(node:929) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will   terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

`nodejs -v` is `v8.4.0` and `npm -v` is `5.3.0`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

From error info:

`Chromium  revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install"`

`cd /path/to/puppeteer && npm install`

this command will download chromium to `/path/to/project/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/`

Comment: Thank you, an incredible time saver!

Comment: I had to do this except I needed to do `node install.js` instead of `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

worked!

Comment: Not for ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Try disable your proxy. Worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didnot set proxy on my system!

Comment: @F.M Are you behind a corporate proxy or something

Comment: I install debian on virtual box and the network is bridge. I don't define proxy on my systems

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Puppeteer removed this error for me. I believe it was caused from upgrading to a later version of Node and then downgrading again.